# Reusable workflow doesn't recognize secrets

Tags: github-actions

I'm running GitHub Actions within my organization's repos. I created a reusable workflow that I apply to multiple repos.

Here is a snippet from the reusable workflow:

```yaml
name: reusable-workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      post_build_custom_command:
        description: "Custom command to run after build"
        required: false
        type: string
        default: ''

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build

    - name: Post Build Custom Command
      run: |
        ${{ inputs.post_build_custom_command }}
      if: ${{ inputs.post_build_custom_command }}
```

I want to specifically focus on the `Post Build Custom Command` task. I created it specifically for a certain repo, which had a lot of similar parts as the reusable workflow, but I had to create this "custom command" input to run a bash script which is custom to that repo.

In my caller repo, I call the reusable workflow as so:

```yaml
name: caller-workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  reusable-workflow:
    name: reusable-workflow
    uses: org/workflows/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      post_build_custom_command: |
        echo "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}" > /tmp/key.pem
    secrets: inherit
```

With the above structure, I'm getting the following error when the actions are triggered:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/workflow.yml (Line: 23, Col: 34): Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'. Located at position 1 within expression: secrets.PRIVATE_KEY
```

I assume it's not possible to use a repo's secrets when I'm using a reusable workflow.

What are my alternatives if I want to keep using the reusable workflow in this repo?

I tried to follow the implementation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow).

My reusable workflow:

```yaml
name: node-ci
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      post_build_custom_command:
        description: "Custom command to run after build"
        required: false
        type: string
        default: ''
    secrets:
      PRIVATE_KEY:
        required: false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Post Build Custom Command
      run: |
        ${{ inputs.post_build_custom_command }}
      if: ${{ inputs.post_build_custom_command }}
```

My caller workflow:

```yaml
name: node-build-trigger

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  node-ci:
    uses: org/workflows/.github/workflows/node-ci.yml@main
    with:
      post_build_custom_command: |
        echo "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"
    secrets:
      PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

The error stays the same.

Comment: It's possible to use secrets in reusable-workflows, but you need to set them in the `workflow_call` configuration. Check [this section of the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow). It might not be transparent here, but I guess you'll have to add the `PRIVATE_KEY` as secret input of the reusable for the reusable workflow to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd - Hope I understood correctly, I edited the post to reflect the changes based on the link you provided. Can you confirm whether my changes are correct?

Comment: Looks good to me now @Daniel (will you always need the secret? If yes, you should maybe set it as `required: true`?)

Comment: @GuiFalourd This secret is only used by a specific repo, so I set it to false on purpose. Thanks for checking out the workflow again, but it seems like I'm still unable to read the secret. Guess it's not as straight forward when `secrets` run in the context of `with:`.

Comment: Yes, the github interpreter might not be able to inherit the secret value from an input in the reusable workflow. In that case, you might have to follow what `jonrsharpe` suggested in his answer: Informing the whole input as a secret in the reusable.

Answer (score -3):

This is happening because the interpolation is attempted in the *calling* workflow. Per [Context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability) (emphasis mine):

| Workflow key | Context | Special functions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `jobs.<job_id>.secrets.<secrets_id>` | `github, needs, strategy, matrix, secrets, inputs, vars` | None |
| `jobs.<job_id>.steps.with` | `github, needs, strategy, matrix, job, runner, env, vars, secrets, steps, inputs` | `hashFiles` |
| `jobs.<job_id>.with.<with_id>` | `github, needs, strategy, matrix, inputs, vars` | None |

As you can see:

- `secrets` are available to `with` in a *step*, but not in a *job*, hence you cannot interpolate `secrets.PRIVATE_KEY` and instead get the *"Unrecognized named-value: 'secrets'."* error; but
- `secrets` are available to `secrets` in a job, so you could potentially pass the whole command *as one secret*.

In your case that would be something like:

```yaml
name: caller-workflow

on: { ... }

jobs:
  reusable-workflow:
    uses: path/to/reusable-workflow.yml
    secrets:
      post_build_custom_command: |
        echo "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}" > /tmp/key.pem
```

```yaml
name: reusable-workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      post_build_custom_command:
        required: false
        
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build
    - name: Post Build Custom Command
      run: ${{ secrets.post_build_custom_command }}
      if: ${{ secrets.post_build_custom_command }}
```

Comment: The first half is definitely correct, I'm quoting the docs, so I guess the suggestion _didn't_ work?